# Given an array of size n. You have to obtain a sum say x using minimum no of elements in x and any element in this array can be used infinitely

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic

Is there a most optimize method to solve this problem. I have a method of solving it in O(nx) can anyone suggest me better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem known as [unbounded knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition). This optimization version of the problem is NP-hard, but there are pseudo-polynomial algorithms that solve it in O(nx).

Here is an example implementation in Python:

```py
def solve(A, x):
    T = [float('inf')]*(x+1)
    T[0] = 0

    for element in A:
        for i in xrange(len(T)-element):
            T[i+element] = min(T[i+element], T[i]+1)

    return T[x]

print solve([5, 2], 10) #2: 5+5 = 10    
print solve([5, 2], 8)  #4: 2+2+2+2 = 8
```

This implementation just returns the minimum number of elements. Finding the actual elements (a single combination, there may be an exponential number of them) is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge.